# Autoprefixer doesn't work in create-react-app while using sass

Tags: reactjs, sass, create-react-app, autoprefixer

I'm using create-react-app and I'm using ".scss" files to style the app, and according to the documentation, autoprefixer should work automatically ...
https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/post-processing-css

Here's my "index.scss" file ...

```
/* autoprefixer grid: on */
@import "./app/css/reset";
@import "./app/css/variables";
@import "./app/css/mixins";
@import "./app/css/global";
@import "./app/css/form";
```

It just imports a bunch of other ".scss" files.

And here's the "index.js" file ...

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import "./index.scss";
import App from "./App";
import { configureStore } from "./app/store/configureStore";


const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
            <App />
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

And here's the [browserslist] in package.json file ...

```
"browserslist": [
    "last 1 version",
    "> 1%",
    "maintained node versions",
    "not dead"
]
```

What am I doing wrong here? Whenever I inspect the CSS I can't see any autoprefixing happening.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your browserlist setting is really modern. This means many of the css prefixes are no longer necessary. Try something like

```
"browserslist": [
    "since 2010" // support all browsers & versions released since 2010
]
```

and you should start to see autoprefixer kicking in.

Here's the [list of queries you can make](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#full-list).

Comment: Perfect !!  Thanks.. !

Comment: i tried changing the queries, but nothing kicked in....   I think react peeps need to update their documentations to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54510905/3559967) worked only for running the development server using `yarn start`.

Autoprefixer did not add the grid prefixes for the production build, despite having `ie 11` in the `browserslist` and the comment `/* autoprefixer grid: autoplace */` in the scss files.

So I had to add the environment variable `AUTOPREFIXER_GRID=autoplace` when running `yarn run build`.

I could get the grid autoprefixing to work either using command line:

```sh
AUTOPREFIXER_GRID=autoplace yarn run build
```

OR

updating `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "AUTOPREFIXER_GRID=autoplace react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

`create-react-app` version: `3.4.1`.

Comment: To enable autoprefixing for grid just add this line

    /* autoprefixer grid: autoplace */
    
to the top of your css/scss file

see https://create-react-app.dev/docs/post-processing-css/. Should do the job :)

Comment: Thank you! I had exactly the same issue.. I've `/* autoprefixer grid: autoplace */` and all works fine on dev but doesn't work in prod build.. this env variable did the fix :)

Answer (score 0):

```
/* autoprefixer grid: autoplace */
```

Did not work for the production build in create-react-app, since it [gets removed in compressed mode](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax/comments).

Solution:

```
/*! autoprefixer grid: autoplace */
```